# Recuperar dado do action Symfony em Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

Oi, eu tenho um botão que dispara uma ação `Ajax` que leva para uma `action` no `controlador Symfony`. No action eu consigo fazer o `select` e ver a informação que eu quero, mas só não consigo buscar isso no Ajax, na `view`. 
Olhem meu código:

ajax:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#idAlterarResponsavelProcedimento").click(function(){

            var pessoaId = $("#procedimentos_pessoa_origem").attr('name');
            var nome = '<?php echo $nomeFamilia?>';
            alert('nome: '+nome);
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/kwadmin_dev.php/admin/procedimentos/get_responsavel_atual',
                data: { pessoa: pessoaId },

                success: function(data) {
                  alert('success - '+JSON.parse(data)); 
                  // $("#procedimentos_pessoa_origem").html(data.pessoa);
                  $("#procedimentos_pessoa_origem").html('estacio');  
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Minha ação:

```
public function executeGet_responsavel_atual(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $pessoa = $request->getParameter('pessoa');

    $this->familiaId = Doctrine::getTable('familias_pessoas')->createQuery('a')
                                            ->select('a.id_familia')
                                            ->where('a.id_pessoa =' . $pessoa)
                                            ->fetchArray();

    $this->familiaNome = Doctrine::getTable('familias')->createQuery('f')
                                                        ->select('nm_familia')
                                                        ->where('id ='. $this->familiaId[0]["id_familia"])
                                                        ->fetchArray();

    $this->nomeFamilia = $this->familiaNome[0]["nm_familia"];

    //echo $this->nomeFamilia;
    //die;
  //        die($nomeFamilia);


}
```

e esse é o meu partial que passa a variavel para a view:

```
   <?php include_partial('form', array('form' => $form,'nomeFamilia' => $nomeFamilia)) ?>
```

Ai no código fonte diz: Notice: Undefined variable: nomeFamilia

eu quero trazer para a tela o resultado que obtive na variavel `$nomeFamilia` , mas não consigo..

Answer (score 1):

bom, por ajax recomendo fazer assim:

inclua o JMS serializer pelo composer e instale

```
"require": {
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1"
    },
```

utilize o JMS para serializar para JSON a entidade e retorne a resposta

```
public function executeGet_responsavel_atual(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $pessoa = $request->getParameter('pessoa');

    $this->familiaId = Doctrine::getTable('familias_pessoas')->createQuery('a')
                                            ->select('a.id_familia')
                                            ->where('a.id_pessoa =' . $pessoa)
                                            ->fetchArray();

    $this->familiaNome = Doctrine::getTable('familias')->createQuery('f')
                                                        ->select('nm_familia')
                                                        ->where('id ='. $this->familiaId[0]["id_familia"])
                                                        ->fetchArray();

    $this->nomeFamilia = $this->familiaNome[0]["nm_familia"];

    $serializedEntity = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($this->nomeFamilia, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('primary')));
    return new Response(serializedEntity);     
}
```

o ajax esta correto, so retirar as desnecessidades:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $("#idAlterarResponsavelProcedimento").click(function(){    
            var pessoaId = $("#procedimentos_pessoa_origem").attr('name');
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/kwadmin_dev.php/admin/procedimentos/get_responsavel_atual',
                data: { pessoa: pessoaId },    
                success: function(data) {
                  var pessoa = JSON.parse(data);
                  $("#procedimentos_pessoa_origem").html(pessoa);
            });
            return false;
        });
```